# Trying to create images with an array of image src attributes using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, image

I have a n array of imag src attributes from images that I was able to push to an array:

```
var imgSrcArray = Array();
$('.ito-image').each(function(){
     imgSrcArray.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

I want to take these attributes now and create new images for a different purpose on my webpage how can I do this. And is this he best practice?

Comment: Have you considered just copying/moving the images to whatever new place you want them appended?

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what u want ?

```
for (var i=0; i < imgSrcArray.length; i++){

  $('body').append("<img src='"+ imgSrcArray[i] +"' />");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate same way using `$.each()` and append to some container div:

```
$(imgSrcArray).each(function (index, item) {

    $("#new").append('<img src="' + item + '"/>');

});
```

or you can directly do it:

```
$('.ito-image').each(function(){
     $("#new").append('<img src="' + $(this).attr("src") + '"/>');
});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/0oh6mma0/